# http package can not convert map to query URL in flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying make an http post request with the method below. when I run the method I keep getting the message that an exeption has occured and am being pointed to this utils.dart file. From what am seeing my best guess is that there is a problem converting the map data I have provided in the url into the query string. Icant seem to find what am doing wrong tho.How may I solve this.

**Request Method**

```
Future<List>getdata()async{

print("Loading ....");
String theUrl ="https://http://127.0.0.1/codeishweb/notifiedUser.php";
var res = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(theUrl),headers: {"Accept":"application/json"},body: {"notID":2},);
var responseBody = json.decode(res.body);

print("results ::$responseBody");
 //print("the response at position something::::\nHeading\n${responseBody[0][7]['post_head']}\nBody\n${responseBody[0][7]['post_body']}");

 return responseBody;
}
```

**Error message in utils.dart**

```
/// Converts a [Map] from parameter names to values to a URL query string.
///
///     mapToQuery({"foo": "bar", "baz": "bang"});
///     //=> "foo=bar&baz=bang"
String mapToQuery(Map<String, String> map, {Encoding encoding}) {
  var pairs = <List<String>>[];
  map.forEach((key, value) => pairs.add([
        Uri.encodeQueryComponent(key, encoding: encoding),
        Uri.encodeQueryComponent(value, encoding: encoding)
      ]));
  return pairs.map((pair) => "${pair[0]}=${pair[1]}").join("&");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand! if you want to pass query parameter then why don't you use `get` request!

Comment: For the task am doing I have to use post

Comment: then instead of using query params why don't you use post params.

Comment: try using `body: json.encode({"notID":2})`

Comment: Try replacing the `2`, with a string literal `'2'`, also post the full error stack if possible

Comment: @Mattia works with the string '2'. Tnx

Comment: This is really bad that you have to convert to string, is there any other option?